# how to vertically align both image and text?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I need to center both image and text vertically. however, something goes wrong in my code and I don't know why. i can get the text to be centered, however, the image is not I have no clue why. any ideas?
this is my code so far.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.settings {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.connecttext {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/How_to_use_icon.svg/1200px-How_to_use_icon.svg.png" class="settings">
    <p class="connecttext"><strong>Connect</strong><br>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `.center` :

```css
.center {
    display: flex;
    place-items: center;
    ...
}
```

Comment: For reference, see [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items).

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
display: flex;
justify-content: center; //for horizontal 
align-items: center; //for vertically align 
}
```